# AttributeError when monkey patching an object in python

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to monkey patch an object in Python.

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__n = 0

    def f(self):
        self.__n += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__n)


c = C()

def up(self):
    self.__n += 2

import types
c.up = types.MethodType(up, c)
c.up()
```

But I got an AttributeError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled4.py", line 19, in <module>
    c.up()
  File "untitled4.py", line 15, in up
    self.__n += 2
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute '__n'
```

How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `up` function isn't declared inside a class, it is not possible to apply [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) rules to its locals, while it is applied for the attribute name. Therefore you'd need to apply the name mangling manually in your function:

```
def up(self):
    self._C__n += 2
```